# React + Styled Components : Every render setState resets all components

Tags: reactjs

I have stumbled on a showstopping mystery with React + Styled Components. I am at a complete loss.

Here's my component:

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from "styled-components";

class SearchBar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            searchStr: '',
            isEditing: false,
            isSearching: false,
            isIdle: true,
            activeMode: 'search'
        };
    }

    onChange=(e)=>{
        console.log("on change input");
        this.setState( {
            ...this.state
        }, () => {
            // nada...
        });
    };


    render () {

        const SearchBarStyle = styled.div`
            height: 85%;
            `;

        return (
            <SearchBarStyle>
                <input type="text" onChange={this.onChange} placeholder="Search"/>
            </SearchBarStyle>
        );
    }
}


export default SearchBar;
```

The problem is this: as soon as I start typing into the `input`, `setState` is invoked. When that happens everything under `<SearchBarStyle>` resets! my first typed character is erased and the input control starts from scratch, showing the placeholder hint...

**Here comes the mindbending stuff:**

If I replace `<SearchBarStyle>` with a simple `div` **OR** I never call `setState` the problem doesn't occur. I can type freely...  Somehow, calling `setState` on a component built with styled-components is resetting it completely!

Whiskey-Tango-Foxtrot!?

Comment: i see problem in setState where you are just setting state to old state again. Nothing wrong with styled-components here

Comment: This isn't the issue. The component has been simplified for Stackoverflow. Why is my <input> being erased every time type into the input field? (which invokes `setState` and resets everything? and why is replacing `<SearchBarStyle>` with a simpe `div` fixes the problem?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the styld-component. Please remove the styled-components tag

Comment: removed the styled-components tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Declare the `SearchBarStyle` above the class.
   Declaring it in `render()` will re-render the component every time you have an update in the `SearchBar` component.

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const SearchBarStyle = styled.div`
  height: 85%;
`;

class SearchBar extends React.Component {
...
```

2. The way you update state is incorrect. It should be:

```
onChange = e => {
  console.log("on change input")
  this.setState({
    searchStr: e.target.value
  }, () => {

  });
};
```

2. Assign the value of state to the input box.

```
  <input type="text" onChange={this.onChange} value={this.state.searchStr} placeholder="Search"/>
```

Comment: This is correct and complete, the focus loss is caused by this

Comment: you are correct! the focus is indeed lost because of this. moving it outside the class resolves the focus issue!

Comment: I updated my answer and elaborate the mistakes in the posted code.

Answer (score 3):

Check this code

Issue #1. Input value not set. Input element should be

```
<input
          value={this.state.searchStr}
          type="text"
          onChange={this.onChange}
          placeholder="Search"
        />
```

Issue #2. target input value is not set in state, your onChange handler should be

```
onChange = e => {
    this.setState({ searchStr: e.target.value });
  };
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-montalcini-mkiyq

Comment: This worked thanks, but now there's another issue. Every keystroke, while updated on the `<input>` causes a focus loss... I have to re-click on the input to regain it.

Comment: thats because of styled-component defined in wrong place.  Updated sandbox code. Now focus is not lost.

Answer (score 1):

You don't use the `state` value as the `input` value and you don't assign the new value to the `state` through `e.target.value`

```
onChange = (e) => {
  console.log("on change input");
  // e.target.value contains the updated value of the input
  this.setState({
    searchStr: e.target.value
  }, () => {
    console.log('state updated', this.state);
  });
};
```

Assign the `searchStr` from `state` to value

```
<input
  type="text"
  value={this.state.searchStr}
  onChange={this.onChange}
  placeholder="Search"
/>
```

To keep the focus of the input define the `SearchBarStyles` above the outside of the `SearchBar` component

```
const SearchBarStyle = styled.div`
  height: 85%;
`;


class SearchBar extends React.Component {
  ..
```

Comment: This worked thanks! but now there's another issue. Every keystroke, while updated on the <input> correctly, causes a focus loss... I have to re-click on the input to be able to type there again

Answer (score 1):

Here you are using [`Uncontrolled Components`](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) so on every `setState` your component is getting re-render and eventually you lost old value.

To solve this issue you must use `Controlled Components` i.e. set the `value` attribute of input to the state value like,

```
<input type="text" onChange={this.onChange} placeholder="Search" value={this.state.searchStr} />
```

Comment: This worked thanks! but now there's another issue. Every keystroke, while updated on the <input> correctly, causes a focus loss... I have to re-click on the input to be able to type there again